# How to use loadingIndicatorSource component in react native

Tags: react-native

I see This Component in official site of React Native. But nothing Example get on the https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#loadingindicatorsource. I only get what is this
Can anyone tell me how I use this Component on react native ?

Answer (score 2):

### You can use loadingindicator like as activityindicator

```
<Image
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "85%",
              alignSelf: "center",
            }}
            resizeMode="contain"
            loadingIndicatorSource={require("../assets/loader2.gif")}
            source={{ uri: item.thumb_url }}
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Image {...props} loadingIndicatorSource={URI} />
```

What does statement above mean?

1. {...props} - is your custom props, like `source` or `style`, for example.
2. URI - is **URI** of image, which will be shown while image, specified in `source` props, is loading.`

Examples:

- `<Image source={{uri: URI}} loadingIndicatorSource={require('loadingIndicatorSource={require('@assets/images/loading.jpeg')}')}`
- `<Image source={{uri: URI}}
  loadingIndicatorSource={{uri:
  'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/128/Emotes-face-smile-icon.png'}} />`

Answer (score -1):

One of the ways I found to use it is passing a component directly, like an ActivityIndicator

```
<Image loadingIndicatorSource={<YOUR LOADING COMPONENT/>} />
```

Comment: can you please show me with a normal example